# Fetching all data from table dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to show all data from table "orders" in my frontend file `order.js`.

I defined route in my `app.js`

```
app.post('/api/myorders', function (req, res) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "orders",
        Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
    };

    docClient.scan(params, onScan);

    function onScan(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            res.send({ success: false,message:JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)})
        } else {
            res.send( {success: true,orders:data.Items})
        }
    }
});
```

In my frontend file `order.js` I am fetching data like this

```
const options = {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                'Authentication': user.getHmac('POST', '/api/myorders')
            },
        };

        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_DB_URI + "/myorders", options)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => {

                console.error("Error:", error)
                setErrors("There was an error getting orders.")
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.success) {
                    console.log("Success:", response)

                }
                else {
                    console.log("Error:", response)
                    setErrors("There was an error getting order.")

                }
            });
```

But constantly getting error

```
"success":false,"message":"{\n  \"message\": \"ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty\",\n  \"code\": \"ValidationException\",\n  \"time\": \"2020-08-30T07:53:06.375Z\",\n  \"requestId\": \"11OEEP6KPETMRVVCBE2RD03MJFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG\",\n  \"statusCode\": 400,\n  \"retryable\": false,\n  \"retryDelay\": 25.696811530071486\n}"}
```

Please any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current state of the APIs, you can't do that. Both scan and query require at least one condition to execute. There is no select all operation available in DDB.

As a work around, you can add a property with a constant value to your data item and store it. Creating a global secondary index on that property, you can use that as the key condition expression to select all records available. But be aware that this will be considered an anti-pattern.